# What velocity do I need to get the moons orbit perfectly aligned with the earths center

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, simulations

I have a simulation for universal gravity with two objects. How can I calculate the velocity or instantaneous force I would need to apply to object 2 (the moon) to get it to orbit so that the origin of the moons path around object 1 (the earth) is at the origin of the earth.

NOTE: The moon is already raised above the earth at the start of the simulation.

Given: Fg, G, m1, m2, r, theta

Comment: See [the Wikipedia article on orbital speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed)

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks I found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for.

[image]